# Google Tag Manager - how can I fire a tag with a specific frequency (i.e. once every 30 days)?

Tags: google-tag-manager

When implementing a Tag inside Google Tag Manager I don't see any option to fire a Tag only with a specific frequency.  For example,

- Fire Tag only once every 30 days
- Fire Tag only once per visitor
- Fire Tag only once per session

I'm migrating over from another tag manager that has a very simple way of doing this so surely I am missing something.  I've looked at implementing Triggers but that doesn't seem to have what I want either.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything, Google Tag Manager will not do this.

You have a few options like setting a start and end date (alas you cannot use variables to set the date), or have a tag fire only once per pageview/event.

However GTM does not set cookies or does anything else to maintain a session, so it has no built-in concept of time passed or visitors with multiple pageviews or anything like it. If you want something like this you'd need to implement a custom javascript variable that writes session/user cookies and build your triggers on that.